# Coding a simple GTK GUI on windows in C with eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, windows, gtk, pkg-config

My problem seems quite simple: I would like to be able to create a simple program with a simple GUI for windows in C (and if possible on windows).
My current environment is eclipse IDE, msys2 with mingw64 toolchain all on windows 10.
I would like to use pkg-config with eclipse to avoid "hard-coding" all my libraries, and for that I first tried the pkg-config plugin for eclipse (it crashes when I create a new project, null pointer exception). I then tried to insert the pkg-config command inside the call to GCC. For that I had to use powershell because cmd do not allow it.
But even on powershell, i'm not able to use it because the string that pkg-config returns me is considered by gcc as a command.
Here is what eclipse uses to compile:

```
powershell gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 --std=c99 $(pkg-config-win --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0) -o main.o "..\\main.c"
```

And here is what it returns me:

```
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mms-bitfields -pthread -mms-bitfields -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0 [...]'
```

I then tried to remove the --cflags of pkg-config: 
Command used by eclipse:

```
powershell gcc $(pkg-config-win --libs gtk+-3.0) -o Test.exe main.o -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lz -lpangowin32-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

And here is the result (8 times the same line).

```
gcc.exe: error: .0: No such file or directory
```

I tried dozens of different things but none of them works.

So my main questions are:

1. Is there a simple way to solve this problem?
2. Do I do the right things (is eclipse made to be able to do such things?)
3. If not, what should I do? (Change IDE? Change GUI library, ...)

I hope that you will be able to help me, I am very open about the possibilities that you might give. Please excuse me if I was unclear on some points or do not give enough informations, I will reply as soon as possible to your questions :p

Comment: It sounds like something is causing the entire `pkg-config` output to be treated as one long argument instead of multiple space-separated arguments. I'm not sure what the fix there is... something in Eclipse?

Comment: I do not know if it is really related to eclipse. 
Here is the command entered in powershell:
    gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 --std=c99 $(p
.o "..\\main.c"

And here is the result:
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mms-bitfields -pthread [...]' 
So it seems that eclipse passes the commands to the console and takes back its answer to display.

Comment: So is it a PowerShell issue then? Does PowerShell treat the replacement of `$(...)` as a single argument?

Comment: How would you check such a thing?

Comment: You can write a simple C program that just prints arguments, one per line, on stdout, then build it and run it like `test.exe $(echo hello world)` from within PowerShell. If the output is `hello` and `world` on separate lines, or if PowerShell complains of invalid syntax, then PowerShell isn't doing it; if the output is `hello world` on one line, then it's PowerShell doing it and different syntax is going to be needed.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. I will try this tomorrow and tell you the results (even if I already got a small idea). By the way, would you know the syntax needed if we are in the second case? I tried some things before coming here (like some random '\') but it did not work.

Comment: I'm looking things up; maybe plain old `cmd` can be used here; hold on...

Comment: EDIT: nope; might as well try this program option. Can you print the output of just the `pkg-config-win` command in the meantime?

Comment: @DrCampy : Getting gtk to work with Windows is nothing but pain. I did manage to compile gtk successfully with Visual Studio following [this](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/Win32/MSVCCompilationOfGTKStack) but it took me almost 3 days to make that obsolete tutorial work. But I believe it is far more difficult to do the same using Eclipse and gcc.. Have heart!!

Comment: Did you make any progress?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is a personnal project and I have other projects for school, I miss some time...
I'll tell you my results ASAP :)
Thanks for your help anyway! :)

Comment: Hi, 
As I had not enough time to try this again and again, I figured out that it would be better to learn C++ and use Qt with QtCreator. It clearly is easier. Thank for your help anyway, that is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> So my main questions are:
>   1.Is there a simple way to solve this problem?
> ```

Yes,

While this is an old question, it deserves an answer. The problem as correctly noted in the comments is the output of `$(pkg-config-win --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0)` is returned as one long string and `gcc` doesn't recognize it. To solve the problem you can simply assign the output of `pkg-config` as an array and use the array variable with `gcc`, e.g.

```
PS> [string[]] $cflags = $(pkg-config-win --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0)
PS> gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 --std=c99 $cflags -o main.o ..\main.c
```

`gcc` will then see each option contained in `$cflags` as an individual argument (an quoting is automatically handled so embedded `'-'` and `'.'` do not cause problems in powershell)